# Number of Unique Paths in a matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, data-structures, dynamic-programming

The problem I encountered is:

> A robot is located at the top-left corner of a m x n grid. The robot can only move either down or right at any point in time. The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid. How many possible unique paths are there?

The code I submitted is:

```
class Solution(object):
    def uniquePaths(self,m,n):

        # m : (int) rows
        # n : (int) cols

        mat = [[0] * n] * m

        for i in range(n):
            mat[0][i] = 1


        for i in range(m):
            mat[i][0] = 1

        for i in range(1,m):
            for j in range(1,n):
                mat[i][j] = mat[i - 1][j] + mat[i][j - 1]

        return mat[m - 1][n - 1]
```

After submission, I got to know that my code was only faster than 21% of other submissions. That means my code is not optimal. So out of curiosity, I checked the other submission which was way faster than mine.

The **better** solution is:

```
class Solution(object):
    def uniquePaths(self, m, n):
        p = 1
        for i in xrange(n,m+n-1):
            p *= i
        return p/self.factorial(m-1)

    def factorial(self,n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        return n*self.factorial(n-1)
```

As you can see, its time complexity is linear while mine was quadratic. But I am not able to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: You are right about the complexity of the facotrial, but i think the factorial function is called for calculating the facotoriak of m only. and the for loop goes on for (m + n - 1 - m) times. so the complexity is O(min(m,n + 1))

Comment: A good question would be to print the all those possible paths as well. I guess then your approach will give you faster results as compared to others!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a computer program for this. It's a simple combinatorics problem. Imagine m right arrows and n down arrows. Another way to ask this question is in how many ways can we arrange these arrows? We can select m spots for right arrows from m+n. So the answer is binomial(m, m + n)